# Image confined to element is cut off even though z-index is larger

Tags: html, css

I have a page that generates a table from an API request. Part of this is an image of the item, which I have created an icon which when the user hovers over, it displays the image for that row. I may have misunderstood how z-index works, but I have set the image z-index to 99 and it still it getting cut off because the element the table sits in is too small.

```css
/* Card Large */
#sets-individual-page .background .card-large {
  background-color: #283046;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}


/* Tables */
#sets-individual-page .background .box-table {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

#sets-individual-page .background .table {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: .8rem;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

#sets-individual-page .background tr {
  min-height: 2rem;
}

#sets-individual-page .background th,
#sets-individual-page .background td {
  padding: .3rem .5rem .2rem .5rem !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#sets-individual-page .background tr .standard > div,
#sets-individual-page .background tr .foil > div {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: .75rem;
  margin: 0;
}

#sets-individual-page .background tr .standard .btn-icon,
#sets-individual-page .background tr .foil .btn-icon,
#sets-individual-page .background tr .standard .btn-icon .icon,
#sets-individual-page .background tr .foil .btn-icon .icon {
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#sets-individual-page .background tr .standard input,
#sets-individual-page .background tr .foil input {
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

#sets-individual-page .background .table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
#sets-individual-page .background .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  color: #f6f6f6;
  background-color: #161d31;
}

#sets-individual-page .background .icon,
#sets-individual-page .background .symbol {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-right: .3rem;
  margin-bottom: .1rem;
}

/* MTG Card Images */
#sets-individual-page .background .large {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 20%;
  top: 15%;
}

#sets-individual-page .background .btn-icon:hover + .large  {
  display: block;
  z-index: 999 !important;
}

#sets-individual-page .background .large-image {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  z-index: 999 !important;
  width: 18.75rem;
  height: 26.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-large">
  <h4 class="">Cards</h4>
  <table class="table table-hover table-sm text-nowrap">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 03%;" class="text-end">
          <h5>#</h5>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 25%;" class="">
          <h5>Name</h5>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 15%;" class="">
          <h5>Type</h5>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 07%;" class="">
          <h5>Rarity</h5>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;" class="">
          <h5>Mana Cost</h5>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="card-listings">
      <tr>
        <td class="text-end">1</td>
        <td class="">
          <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-primary">
            <img class="icon" src="/static/img/icons/image.png">
          </span>
          <span class="large">
            <img class="large-image" src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/c/7/c7bbb911-9de2-455d-9677-e1004db65dbd.jpg?1593559500" height="500">
          </span>
          Chandra, Torch of Defiance
        </td>
        <td class="">Legendary Planeswalker — Chandra</td>
        <td class="">Mythic</td>
        <td class="">
          <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/2.png">
          <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
          <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-end">2</td>
        <td class="">
          <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-primary">
            <img class="icon" src="/static/img/icons/image.png">
          </span>
          <span class="large">
            <img class="large-image" src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/8/c/8c1a02f9-3ce7-46e9-8d0e-0d491bb13012.jpg?1593559582" height="500">
          </span>
          Cathartic Reunion
        </td>
        <td class="">Sorcery</td>
        <td class="">Rare</td>
        <td class="">
          <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/1.png">
          <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**screenshot**

[image]

**EDIT:**

- added html of card element
- added css of card element

Comment: Have you tried scrolling you page after adding more content? It will not add scrollbars because it's position is absolute. Z-index has nothing to do with cutting content, it's just how "high" element is, so it can hide behind other element. And I don't see any `overflow:` rule

Comment: I can scroll that card element down to see the rest of the image, however I'm trying to get it to appear above the card element so the user does not need to scroll to see the image.

Comment: Then reduce size of your image, no other way. If element does not fit to page, you _must_ scroll or it will be partly hidden. How do you image it will pop out of your browser window?

Comment: try to `object-fit: cover` on your image.

Comment: The image itself fit on the page perfectly fine. It just doesn't fit in the element that table is in therefore is being cut off by the element. If the image can be displayed above that element there is more than enough space to see the whole image. Adding `object-fit: cover` didn't change anything.

Comment: @Ross Please include the rest of your HTML and CSS for the table. It will be helpful.

Comment: @TannerDolby Added the html for the whole card element.

Comment: @Ross Thanks! If you have the CSS to make it look like the image you included in your question that would be superb.

Comment: @TannerDolby added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your card image isn't appearing at the top of stack and above the `<div class="card-large">` container like you expect when giving it the highest [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) value is because the `<img>` elements are absolutely positioned **relative** to the parent `.card-large`. Since the images are absolutely positioned relative to the parent div, they are essentially constrained to that content box.

If you nest your `.card-large` container in its own parent `<div>` and give the new parent `position: relative`, your images will appear at the top of stacking context when the `.icon` images are hovered and display above the `.card-large` container like expected.

```css
/* Card Large */
.wrapper {
 position: relative;
}

.card-large {
  background-color: #283046;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-large > h4 {
 color: #eee;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 margin: 0;
}

/* Tables */
#sets-individual-page .background .box-table {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.table {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: .8rem;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

.table tr {
  min-height: 2rem;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: .3rem .5rem .2rem .5rem !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table tr .standard > div,
.table tr .foil > div {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: .75rem;
  margin: 0;
}

#sets-individual-page .background tr .standard .btn-icon,
#sets-individual-page .background tr .foil .btn-icon,
#sets-individual-page .background tr .standard .btn-icon .icon,
#sets-individual-page .background tr .foil .btn-icon .icon {
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.table tr .standard input,
.table tr .foil input {
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
 .background .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  color: #f6f6f6;
  background-color: #161d31;
}

.table .icon,
.table .symbol {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-right: .3rem;
  margin-bottom: .1rem;
}

/* MTG Card Images */
.large {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 20%;
  top: 15%;
}

.btn-icon:hover + .large  {
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  
}

.large-image {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 18.75rem;
  height: 26.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card-large">
    <h4>Cards</h4>
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm text-nowrap">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 03%;" class="text-end">
            <h5>#</h5>
          </th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 25%;" class="">
            <h5>Name</h5>
          </th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 15%;" class="">
            <h5>Type</h5>
          </th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 07%;" class="">
            <h5>Rarity</h5>
          </th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;" class="">
            <h5>Mana Cost</h5>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td class="text-end">1</td>
           <td class="">
            <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-primary">
              ️
              <img class="icon" src="/static/img/icons/image.png">
            </span>
            Chandra, Torch of Defiance
             <span class="large">
              <img class="large-image" src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/c/7/c7bbb911-9de2-455d-9677-e1004db65dbd.jpg?1593559500" height="500">
            </span>
            Chandra, Torch of Defiance
          </td>
          <td class="">Legendary Planeswalker — Chandra</td>
          <td class="">Mythic</td>
          <td class="">
            <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/2.png">
            <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
            <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-end">2</td>
          <td class="">
            <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-primary">
              ️
              <img class="icon" src="/static/img/icons/image.png">
            </span>
            <span class="large">
              <img class="large-image" src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/8/c/8c1a02f9-3ce7-46e9-8d0e-0d491bb13012.jpg?1593559582" height="500">
            </span>
            Cathartic Reunion
          </td>
          <td class="">Sorcery</td>
          <td class="">Rare</td>
          <td class="">
            <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/1.png">
            <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
          </td>
          </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
           <td class="text-end">3</td>
           <td class="">
            <span class="btn-icon btn-icon-primary">
              ️
              <img class="icon" src="/static/img/icons/image.png">
            </span>
            Chandra, Torch of Defiance
             <span class="large">
              <img class="large-image" src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/c/7/c7bbb911-9de2-455d-9677-e1004db65dbd.jpg?1593559500" height="500">
            </span>
            Chandra, Torch of Defiance
          </td>
          <td class="">Legendary Planeswalker — Chandra</td>
          <td class="">Mythic</td>
          <td class="">
            <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/2.png">
            <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
            <img class="symbol" src="/static/img/symbology/R.png">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `display: flow-root;` instead of "block" in the `.btn-icon:hover + .large{}` selector ?

Flow-root display creates a new block formating context that may allow the large-images to overflow the whole table. It is mostly used as a clearfix method and I don't know if it works on table elements, but it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything I'm afraid.